# How to reset pagination in datastore-Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1

Currently I added one feature to navigate to one page and show the filtered records , but the page is using pagination so the issue is like it's filtering individual pages and showing filtered records in different pages

Is there any method to reset pagination and showing all the filtered records in single page